# Parsing string recursively does not work

Tags: haskell

I am struggling with the following problem:

Given :

**Type** `data T=AA | BB | CC deriving (Show)` 
**Input** string `str`   
I am trying to find all occurences of the data constructors inside my given string and append them to the output:
**Example**:
**Input:**`"AABCC"`
**Output:** `[AA,CC]`
Basically i try to parse the string and if the prefix matches i append the second element of the tuple to the result and chop the length from the input string.Else i chop 1 element and try again.

```
titles = [("AA",AA),("BB",BB),("CC",CC)]

rds::String->[T]
rds str = go  str  where  
          go []=[]
          go (x:xs)=case filter ((isPrefixOf str).fst) titles of
                         (name,value):_ ->value:go (drop (length name) (x:xs))
                         [] -> go xs
```

The method works for only 1 element e.g: `"AA"`.When trying bigger inputs i get the `[]` result.

I suppose it has to do with the fact that i am not binding the result to the recursive call of `go`? Does `go` have to have the result as its parameter ,like :
`go [] str;go result []=result ; go result (x:xs)=....`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
go (x:xs) = case filter ((isPrefixOf str).fst) titles of ...
```

you probably want `` (`isPrefixOf` (x:xs)) `` instead.

Comment: **Disclaimer**:*Noob question*: How can i debug this kind of errors? Can you debug line by line Haskell?Or how can i "step" inside the function and see how it evaluates?So far i have learned about `trace`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: See the GHC manual. Specifically https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-ghci-debugger, which explains how to do breakpoints and single stepping in GHCi.